# CSS/HTML: Child DIV overflows parent

Tags: css, html, height, overflow

How can I make the parent DIV wrap around the child DIVs? The problem lies with `position:absolute` in `.nav-content`.

http://jsfiddle.net/9H77Y/8/

EDIT: Well, apparently what I want is impossible. The only way to work around this would be javascript which would defeat the purpose of this in the first place. However, setting a fixed height to `nav-tabs` will work.

HTML

```
<div class="nav-tabs-wrapper">
  <div class="nav-tabs">
    <div class="nav-tab">
      <input type="radio" id="tab1" name="nav-group" checked>
      <label for="tab1">foooooooo</label>
      <div class="nav-content">
        <div> stuff1 </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-tab">
      <input type="radio" id="tab2" name="nav-group">
      <label for="tab2">bar</label>
      <div class="nav-content">
        <div> stuff2 </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.nav-tabs-wrapper
{
    padding: 10px; /* separates the code from other content */
    border: 1px solid #F00; /* visibility aid */
}
.nav-tabs
{
    position: relative; /* needed as future positioning reference base */
            clear: both;
            height: 200px; /* Unfortunate */
    padding-left: 10px; /* provides the paragraph-tab effect to the tabs */
    font: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.nav-tab
{
    float: left; /* keeps the tabs inline with no gap [inline-block introduces gaps] */
}
.nav-tab label
{
    display: block; /* needed so tabs can be positioned correctly to hide nav-content border */
    position: relative; /* needed to position tabs correctly */
    top: 1px; /* lowers the tabs to cover the border of nav-content; needed so bottom corners aren't slanted, but a 90deg angle */
    padding: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-bottom-width: 0px; /* removes bottom border; needed so bottom corners aren't slanted, but a 90deg angle */
    background-color: #CCC;
}
.nav-tab [type=radio]
{
    display: none; /* hide the radio selectors */
}
.nav-tab [type=radio]:checked ~ label
{
    z-index: 2; /* makes sure that the active tab is drawn above nav-content to cover border */
    background-color: #FFF; /* covers the nav-content border */
}
.nav-tab [type=radio]:checked ~ .nav-content
{
    visibility: visible !important; /* unhides the nav-content div for the current tab */
}
.nav-tab:nth-child(n+2)
{
    margin-left: -1px; /* positions the left border of every second+ tab over the previous tab's right border */
}
.nav-content
{
    visibility: hidden; /* hides the content by default */
    position: absolute; /* positions the content for all tabs to the absolute left relative to the tabs */
    left: 0; /* undo's the padding from the paragraph-tab effect */
    width: 100%; /* fills the nav-content DIV completely for a better looking border */
    z-index: 1; /* makes sure that the border is drawn under the tabs */
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
.nav-content div
{
    padding: 10px; /* separate div needed to keep nav-content from overflowing due to padding */
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you haven't given the child elements any height?

Comment: Well, the only elements that would need any set height would be the labels themselves and the div inside nav-content (or perhaps nav-content itself). However, the height for the labels (i.e. tabs) are automatically set. And the height for the content depends on what's inside each tab; I would like for the height to be calculated automatically depending on each tab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't account for `position:absolute` elements.

They are completely removed from the flow of the document.

Quoting the [Specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#choose-position)

> **absolute**
>   The box's position (and possibly size) is specified with the '*top*', '*right*', '*bottom*', and '*left*' properties. These properties specify offsets with respect to the box's containing block. ***Absolutely positioned boxes are taken out of the normal flow***. This means ***they have no impact on the layout of later siblings***. Also, though absolutely positioned boxes have margins, they do not collapse with any other margins.

Answer (score 2):

Give a definite height to .nav-tab and give overflow:auto (or overflow:hidden) to .nav-tabs-wrapper